# Target.sendMessageToTarget is deprecated – how do I use the flattened style of the devtools protocol now?

Tags: puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

Right now a command I am sending command to targets by wrapping the actual message into a `Target.sendMessageToTarget` message. I thought with the "flattened" version I would simply need to add `sessionId` as parameter in the requests, but that doesn't seem to work, e.g.:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "method": "Network.enable",
    "params": {"sessionId":"BC34555752DB5344363E505E6D7C5C"}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-sendMessageToTarget

Answer (score 3):

Solved it myself; leaving it here in case someone encounters the same problem:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "method": "method.name",
    "sessionId": "BC34555752DB5344363E505E6D7C5C",
    "params": { ... }
}
```

`sessionId` must be an entry of the command, not a param.